# How to make a turing transducer for assignment operation, y := x?

Tags: turing-machines

So, consider I have a toy imperative language which ofcourse supports assignment operations. I want to convert each statement of this language into an equivalent turing machine transition. So, the operation `y:=x` can where I have `y` and `x` spread out on a tape (with `>` marking the start and a trail if infinite `$` marking the end) with a `#` in the. middle something like, `>y1,y2...yk#x1,x2,....xk$` I need to make the LHS of the `#` equal to the RHS where $y_i, x_i \in \{0,1\}$ i.e I can have something like `>10100011#11010011111$` .Do you have any idea how do I do this?

Comment: At the beginning all tape cells are "unmarked". Start by deleting the RHS, including the \$ symbol. Then repeat the following: go at the beginning of the LHS, move right until you find the first unmarked symbol, "store" the symbol and go right until you find the first empty symbol, write the symbol. Stop when no unmarked symbols in the LHS are left. Unmark everything, append \$, and you are done.

Comment: That's the thing, I can't delete anything, as I might need x later in the program.

Comment: I just noticed that the algorithm described above copies the LHS to the RHS, but you are asking for the opposite. Clearly the same approach works for that case too.